# Why does Edward call his sparkly skin "the skin of a killer"?

Tags: character, dialogue, the-twilight-saga

In *Twilight*, why does Edward call his sparkly skin "the skin of a killer" when it's actually the skin of a unicorn?

Comment: Do you have a source of "skin of a unicorn", I think you may have misunderstood? - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15894/why-do-vampires-sparkle-in-twilight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because from nature he is a vampire and used to quench their thirst of blood he killed many peoples in in this sense  he called himself  "skin of killer"

Answer (score 7):

Because he's a vampire, and vampires are killers by nature, he's pointing out the irony of that beautiful shiny skin being the skin of such an evil creature.